# Setting up an Angular project with both PrimeNg Diamond template and PrimeBlocks

Tags: angular, primeng

How to set up Angular project with PrimeNg template and PrimeBlocks?

I bought both PrimeNg Diamond template and PrimeBlocks. I want to have the two templates in one Angular project.
I tried to install Diamond template first, and then add themes and styles manually from PrimeBlocks but not everything works as it should.
Please can someone tell me how to set up my Angular project with both Diamond and PrimeBlocks?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not using PrimeFaces (UI component library for Java Server Faces).